# For loop keeps returning empty arrays

Tags: python

I need some help with a for loop I have been trying to run. This is the code I have-

```
cal_points = []
cal_stars = np.genfromtxt('M67_Calibration_Star_List.csv', delimiter = ',', names = True)

radii = 0.00023 

for star in range(len(cal_stars)):
    ra_l = cal_stars[star][1] - radii; ra_u = cal_stars[star][1]+radii
    dec_l = cal_stars[star][2]-radii; dec_u = cal_stars[star][2] + radii 
    for i in range(len(M67_catalogue)):
        if ra_l <= M67_catalogue[i]['RA'] <= ra_u and dec_l <= M67_catalogue[i]['DEC'] <= dec_u:
            cal_points = cal_points+[star]

cal_points.sort()
print(len(cal_points))
print(cal_points)
```

This keeps returning len(cal_points) as 0 and cal_points as []

These are headers in the csv file with a few of the row entries

[image: [CSV file]]

Please tell me where I'm going wrong

Comment: can you post a five row version of the csv as a text instead of an image?

Comment: the list  `cal_point` is being populated if the conditional stament `ra_l <= M67_catalogue[i]['RA'] <= ra_u and dec_l <= M67_catalogue[i]['DEC'] <= dec_u` gives `True`.maybe in your data this condition is never met.

Comment: If you are going to search and compare catalogues by separation between their entries, you're better off using something like `astropy.coordinates` than coding your own double loop. For example, your variable is named `radii` (`radius` seems more apt), but your search area is a square area.

Comment: @python_user would you mean something like this....                                            
 Full RAJ2000 DEJ2000 VTmag gmag rmag imag ok
1 132.820796 11.845963 11.095 11.617 10.748 10.526 0.067
2 132.941947 11.604885 11.166 11.563 10.968 10.84 0.023
3 132.836617 11.890582 11.248 11.436 11.143 11.188 0.082
4 132.707022 11.585678 11.266 11.892 10.92 10.711 0.025
5 132.860095 11.730741 11.273 11.341 11.355 11.591 0.031
6 132.926493 11.856387 11.298 11.822 10.936 10.69 0.092
7 132.840603 11.877171 11.325 11.646 11.14 11.061 0.091

Comment: @Andrex I know the condition should be met as there are several other people who have used this same code to obtain values

Comment: @00 Im not sure i understand, how should i use astropy.coordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are trying to match a (small) catalogue of calibration stars with a catalogue of stars in M67, within a given radius(*), you may as well use `astropy`. Astropy can do all the matching for you, and takes into account the effect of latitudinal distance "shrinking" on a sphere.

Here's some example code that creates two random DataFrames with calibration and catalogue positions, converts them to appropriate Astropy `SkyCoord`s and matches the two sets of positions. It then uses the result to find the stars in the corresponding DataFrames, and concatenates the results into a single DataFrame, including the relevant other information from the catalogue, such as the magnitude.

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import default_rng

rng = default_rng()
n = 30
cal_stars = pd.DataFrame({'RAJ2000': 132 + rng.random(n),
                          'DECJ2000': 11 + rng.random(n),
                          'VTmag': 11 + rng.random(n)})
n = 200
M67_catalogue = pd.DataFrame({'RA': 132 + rng.random(n),
                              'DEC': 11 + rng.random(n),
                              'VTmag': 11 + rng.random(n)})

# Create coordinate arrays, using the relevant columns 
# from the DataFrame
cal_stars_sc = SkyCoord(cal_stars['RAJ2000'] * u.deg,
                        cal_stars['DECJ2000'] * u.deg)
M67_catalogue_sc = SkyCoord(M67_catalogue['RA'] * u.deg,
                            M67_catalogue['DEC'] * u.deg)

# Slightly larger radius in this example; 
# 0.00023 is too precise for the random coordinates used here
sep = 0.023 * u.deg

# `idxm67` are the indices into the M67_catalogue_sc SkyCoord 
# that have a counterpart within `sep` in `cal_stars_sc`. 
# Similarly for `idxcal`
# Note that an index (and thus a coordinate) may appear multiple times:
# a single source may be within `sep` distance to several sources in the 
# other catalogue
idxm67, idxcal, dist, _ = cal_stars_sc.search_around_sky(M67_catalogue_sc, sep)


# We need to use `.iloc`, since `SkyCoord` follows standard (NumPy) indexing
# Thus we need to ignore any index that the Pandas DataFrame may have
df1 = cal_stars.iloc[idxcal, :]
df2 = M67_catalogue.iloc[idxm67, :]
df2.columns = ['M67' + name for name in df2.columns]

# We also want to reset both DataFrame indices, because these were copied above when using iloc
# Resetting them will make sure df1 and df2 have the same indices 
# and are compatible to be concatenated.
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)

# axis=1 means to concatenate along the columns.
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)

# Add the found distances to the final DataFrame
df['dist'] = dist

print(df)
```

---

(*) I assume you want a radius, given the variable name, but the search in your code is within a rectangular region.

---

Here's the short version, without comments and creation of random data. It should be plug and play, provided M67_catalogue is actually a DataFrame (not a NumPy array). Note that the second half, the creation of a matched DataFrame, is a bonus. `cal_stars.iloc[idxcal, :]` after using `search_round_sky` is enough to get your result.

```
import pandas as pd
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord
import astropy.units as u

cal_stars = pd.read_csv('M67_Calibration_Star_List.csv')

radius = 0.00023
cal_stars_sc = SkyCoord(cal_stars['RAJ2000'] * u.deg,
                        cal_stars['DECJ2000'] * u.deg)
M67_catalogue_sc = SkyCoord(M67_catalogue['RA'] * u.deg,
                            M67_catalogue['DEC'] * u.deg)

idxm67, idxcal, dist, _ = cal_stars_sc.search_around_sky(M67_catalogue_sc, radius * u.deg)

df1 = cal_stars.iloc[idxcal, :]
df2 = M67_catalogue.iloc[idxm67, :]
df2.columns = ['M67' + name for name in df2.columns]
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
df['dist'] = dist
print(df)
```